# Not able to covert a Array RDD into List RDD in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

How do I convert a Array[String] RDD into List[String] RDD?

```
scala> val linesRDD = sc.textFile("/user/inputfiles/records.txt")
linesRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at textFile at <console>:21

scala> linesRDD.collect
res17: Array[String] = Array(100,surender,CTS,CHN, 101,ajay,CTS,BNG, 102,kumar,TCS,BNG, 103,Ankit,CTS,CHN, 104,Sukanya,TCS,BNG

scala> linesRDD.toList
<console>:24: error: value toList is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
          linesRDD.toList
```

As you can see above that it throws error.

But if you can see below that , if i apply a take Action and then applying **toList** works

```
scala> linesRDD.take(2).toList
res19: List[String] = List(100,surender,CTS,CHN, 101,ajay,CTS,BNG)
```

How do I convert a Array[String] RDD into List[String] RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear, you are trying to apply a method that doesn't exist in the [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) class.

> error: value toList is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
>             linesRDD.toList

However, to solve this you can `collect` then use `toList`. BTW don't forget that when the data is collected, all of it is moved to the driver, and if it doesn't fit there, you will receive an exception.

```scala
linesRDD.collect.toList
```

Comment: So Does the data get moved to driver machine whenever we apply some Action against any RDD?

Comment: Not all actions, e.g if you `collect` it will, if you `take` it moves those n rows to the driver, but  if you `count` it won't cause it is easy to parallelize.